# Prove $Ab^x$ is injective using $b^x=1$, only when $x = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

How do I use $b^x = 1$ to prove injectivity?

Comment: When is $Ab^x=Ab^y$?

Comment: That's false if $A = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show injectivity, you need to show that $f(x) = f(y)$ implies that $x=y$. Here, $f(x)=Ab^x$ and we also need to assume that $A \ne 0$.

Start of by supposing that $Ab^x = Ab^y$. Now divide both sides by $Ab^y$ to obtain:

$$\frac{Ab^x}{Ab^y} = 1$$

Notice now that the left hand side reduces to (using properties of exponents):
$$b^{x-y} = 1$$

Can you finish now using your hint?